# Solve this equation over natural numbers

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I have this equation : $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \gt 40$$   and     $$x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5\in\{1,2,3,\dots , 13\}$$ and also $x_1$ , $x_2$ , $x_3$ , $x_4$ and $x_5$ isn't equal. I want to find all solutions using Mathematica . I don't know how write this equation in Mathematica.

Please Help!

Comment: This sort of thing is really in the documentation. Look up `Solve` or `diophantine` for example.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: I find nothing there.

Comment: (1) Help > Wolfram Documentation > Solve > Examples > Basic Examples  > Solve an equation over the positive integers:
`Solve[2 x + 3 y == 4 && 3 x - 4 y <= 5 && x - 2 y > -21, {x, 
  y}, Integers]
{{x -> -7, y -> 6}, {x -> -4, y -> 4}, {x -> -1, y -> 2}}` (2) Help > Wolfram Documentation Solve > Examples > Scope > Diophantine Equations >
Linear systems of equations and inequalities:
`Solve[2 x + 3 y == 4 && 3 x - 4 y <= 5 && x - 2 y > -21, {x, 
  y}, Integers]
{{x -> -7, y -> 6}, {x -> -4, y -> 4}, {x -> -1, y -> 2}}`. Modify one or the other to handle your particular inequalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sol = Flatten[#, 1] &@
   Table[Select[IntegerPartitions[i, {5}, Range@13], 
     Length@# == Length@DeleteDuplicates@# &], {i, 41, 13 + 12 + 11 + 10 + 9}]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.00225, Null}

```
Length@sol
```

> 280

These are all unique solutions (if you drop `Select` you'll see that only $1694$ partitions are generated in total, from which one leaves $280$ that satisfy the condition); note the order is neglected, but any permutation is a valid solution.

```
sol
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is simply professional. Do you take into account possible permutations?

Comment: "note the order is neglected, but any permutation is a valid solution"; there are $5!=120$ permutations for each elem of `sol`, so if the order is important then there are $120\times280=33600$ solutions. See also `Permutations`.

Comment: I used this code , but didn't get all of solutions. Just number of them

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake . Thank You a lot!

Comment: @corey979 I asked this question in math.stackexchange.com but nobody can't solve it until now . Can you help me to find 280 number using combinations ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to go about this problem. The first is to use `FindInstance`. Part of the input for `FindInstance` is the number of required solutions, so that might not give you the entire solution set. Finding the first 5 solutions:

```
FindInstance[
 x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 > 40 && 0 < x1 < 14 && 0 < x2 < 14 && 
  0 < x3 < 14 && 0 < x4 < 14 && 0 < x5 < 14, {x1, x2, x3, x4, 
  x5}, Integers, 5]
(*{{x1 -> 13, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 6, x4 -> 13, x5 -> 8}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 12, 
  x3 -> 7, x4 -> 2, x5 -> 12}, {x1 -> 9, x2 -> 12, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 10,
   x5 -> 11}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 7, x4 -> 9, 
  x5 -> 13}, {x1 -> 10, x2 -> 13, x3 -> 4, x4 -> 6, x5 -> 8}}*)
```

There are not all that many combinations of `{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}`, so directly testing the solution space is another option.

```
sols = DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
     If[y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 > 40, {x1 -> y1, x2 -> y2, x3 -> y3, 
       x4 -> y4, x5 -> y5}], {y1, 1, 13}, {y2, 1, 13}, {y3, 1, 
      13}, {y4, 1, 13}, {y5, 1, 13}], 4], Null];
```

From here you can find the number of solutions directly:

```
Length@sols
(*96915*)
```

You can also use `Reduce` to find constraints on `{x1,x2,x3,x4,x5}`:

```
Reduce[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 > 40 && 0 < x1 < 14 && 0 < x2 < 14 && 
  0 < x3 < 14 && 0 < x4 < 14 && 0 < x5 < 14]
```

Comment: The output ofthe last command is (0 < x5 < 
    12 && ((0 < x4 <= 12 - x5 && 12 - x4 - x5 < x3 < 14 && 
       26 - x3 - x4 - x5 < x2 < 14 && 
       40 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5 < x1 < 14) || (12 - x5 < x4 < 
        14 && ((0 < x3 <= 26 - x4 - x5 && 
           26 - x3 - x4 - x5 < x2 < 14 && 
           40 - x2 - x3 - x4 - x5 < x1 < 14) || (26 - x4 - x5 < x3 < 
            14 && ...
               0 < x1 < 14))) || (40 - x4 - x5 <= x3 < 14 && 
           0 < x2 < 14 && 0 < x1 < 14)))))

Comment: Also the condition "x1, x2 , x3 , x4 and x5 are't equal" is not taken into account.

Comment: I didn't see that constraint. If it is truly of the form `x1 != x2 != x3 != x4 != x5` all you need to do is modify the conditional: `sols = DeleteCases[
   Flatten[Table[
     If[y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 + y5 > 40 && 
       y1 != y2 != y3 != y4 != y5, {x1 -> y1, x2 -> y2, x3 -> y3, 
       x4 -> y4, x5 -> y5}], {y1, 1, 13}, {y2, 1, 13}, {y3, 1, 
      13}, {y4, 1, 13}, {y5, 1, 13}], 4], Null];`. Now the number of solutions `Length@sols` is reduced to 33600.

Answer (score 2):

```
vars = Array[x, 5];
```

To avoid equivalent permutations of the solutions use

```
Less @@ vars

(*  x[1] < x[2] < x[3] < x[4] < x[5]  *)
```

This will also ensure your requirement that

```
Unequal @@ vars

(*  x[1] != x[2] != x[3] != x[4] != x[5]  *)

total = 40;

max = 13;

eqns = {Total[vars] > total, Thread[1 <= vars <= max],
    Less @@ vars} // Flatten;

Length[solns = vars /. Solve[eqns, vars, Integers]]

(*  280  *)
```

Comment: My code contains your suggestion Less @@ vars.

Comment: @user64494 - The appropriate use of `Apply (@@)`, `Thread`, and `Total` are important concepts for the OP to learn.

Comment: @ Bob Hanlon: Indeed. Thank you. Now I know more about Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

In this way :

```
vars = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 5}]
vars /. Solve[{Total[vars] > 40, 1 <= x1 <= 13, 1 <= x2 <= 13, 
1 <= x3 <= 13, 1 <= x4 <= 13, 1 <= x5 <= 13, 
x1 < x2 < x3 < x4 < x5}, vars, Integers]
```

The calculated result is as below :

> {{1,4,11,12,13},{1,5,10,12,13},{1,5,11,12,13},<<274>>,{8,9,11,12,13},{8,10,11,12,13},{9,10,11,12,13}}

Answer (score 1):

There are too many solutions to be displayed. Even

```
Solve[{Sum[x[j], {j, 1, 5}] > 40 && x[1] >= 1 && x[1] <= 13 && x[2] >= 1 && x[2] <= 13 && x[3] >= 1 && x[3] <= 13 && x[4] >= 1 &&  x[4] <= 13 && x[5] >= 1 && x[5] <= 13 &&   x[1] < x[2] < x[3] < x[4] < x[5]}, {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4],x[5]}, Integers]
```

> {{x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 4, x[3] -> 11, x[4] -> 12, 
>     x[5] -> 13}, {x[1] -> 1, x[2] -> 5, x[3] -> 10, x[4] -> 12, 
>     x[5] -> 13},...,{x[1] -> 9, x[2] -> 10, x[3] -> 11, x[4] -> 12, x[5] -> 13}}